# How to run Jest test for react-native and web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I want to run my test for **Button.js, Button.ios.js, Button.androind.js** and take separate snapshots for different platforms. How can i do this ?

```
import "react-native";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import Button from "..../Button";

test('Example of test', () => {
    const c = renderer.create(
        <Button text="asd" />
    );
    expect(c.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This example creates snapshot only for native Button and ignores regular HTML component.

Versions:

```
 "react-native": "^0.39.2",
 "jest": "^18.0.0",
```

Comment: react native version?

Comment: @Codesingh, react-native: ^0.39.2

Comment: did you upgraded react native for jest ?

Comment: @Codesingh, yes

Comment: show me your package.json

Comment: @Codesingh, still can not find out how do do this. Here is my package.json http://pastebin.com/ZfVX2MVm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using react-native-web to get your HTML output, you should know that Jest won't actually run your react-native code through webpack and thus it won't handle the react-native -> react-native-web alias, so you'll never see the actual HTML in your snapshot.

That said, you can still make sure your code is working as expected on the platform of your choice.  In our case, we sometimes have different code branches for android and/or web.  We built this simply helper to allow us to easily mock the different platform:

```
const withPlatform = (platform: string, testFunction: () => void) => {
  const origOS = Platform.OS;
  Platform.OS = platform;
  try {
    testFunction();
  } finally { // eslint-disable-line  brace-style
    Platform.OS = origOS;
  }
};
```

Once you have imported into your test, you can then do cool things like:

```
  describe('on the web', () => {
    it('should render correctly', () => {
      withPlatform('web', () => {
        expect(renderer(<SomeComponent />)).toMatchSnapshot(); 
      });
    });
  });
```